# Edit/Customize the Single Page of a Genesis Sample Child Theme

Tags: custom-post-types, genesis-theme-framework

I got my 'Page' and 'Blog List' Page working.. But when i click on one of my Post... the Layout is different .. I want to edit it. Where can i find that?

I tried to edit it..

```
<?php
/*
 WARNING: This file is part of the core Genesis framework. DO NOT edit
 this file under any circumstances. Please do all modifications
 in the form of a child theme.
 */

/**
 * This file handles posts, but only exists for the sake of
 * child theme forward compatibility.
 *
 * This file is a core Genesis file and should not be edited.
 *
 * @category Genesis
 * @package  Templates
 * @author   StudioPress
 * @license  http://www.opensource.org/licenses/gpl-license.php GPL v2.0 (or later)
 * @link     http://www.studiopress.com/themes/genesis
 */

genesis();
```

I guess this isnt the correct file to edit.. What should i do...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You edit the post page by using Genesis hooks ([actions](http://my.studiopress.com/docs/hook-reference/) and / or [filters](http://my.studiopress.com/docs/filter-reference/)). You can do this in the `functions.php` file or in a [WordPress template file](http://codex.wordpress.org/Templates_Hierarchy) located in your child theme directory.

If you use a template file, add the `genesis()` function call to the end of that file and you action and filters calls above it.

For example, here is a `single.php` child theme file which changes the default Post Info (the byline) and the Post Meta (the categories, tags, etc. line) for a post.

```
<?php

/** Customize the post info function. */
add_filter( 'genesis_post_info', 'wpse_108715_post_info_filter' );

/** Customize the post meta function. */
add_filter( 'genesis_post_meta', 'wpse_108715_post_meta_filter' );

genesis();

/**
 * Change the default post information line.
 */
function wpse_108715_post_info_filter( $post_info ) {
    $post_info = '[post_author_posts_link] [post_date]';
    return $post_info;
}

/**
 * Change the default post meta line.
 */
function wpse_108715_post_meta_filter( $post_meta ) {
    $post_meta = '[post_categories] [post_edit] [post_tags] [post_comments]';
    return $post_meta;
}
```

I used the post [shortcode functions](http://my.studiopress.com/docs/shortcode-reference/) provided by Genesis in these functions.